# SugarCrm - How to send e-mail to manager every time a Lead is updated?

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm new to SugarCRM.

I've google but I can't find a solution for this. Every time a Lead is UPDATED (New Log Call, New Email Attached, New meeting, Status Change) I need to send an e-mail.

How can I do this in SugarCrm?

Best Regards,
André

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the benefits of blasting a person with an email upon every update can be argued against, what you will need to do is use an after_save logic hook on the Leads module. Within that hook you would then send an email if it is an existing lead.

Helpful links:

- http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.6/60_Logic_Hooks/20_Module_Hooks/after_save/
- http://developer.sugarcrm.com/2011/02/14/howto-detect-record-state-in-a-logic-hook/
- http://developer.sugarcrm.com/2011/03/01/howto-send-an-email-inside-sugar-thru-code/

Comment: Hi egg. Thanks for your reply but when I add a "Call" or a "Meeting" to a Lead the "after_save" will not work. What can I do about this?

Comment: In those cases use an after_save hook on the Calls, Meetings, Tasks, and Notes modules. Check if it is a lead within those hooks.

Comment: Hi again egg. Thanks for your comment one more time. Do you know any documentation where I can find how to query this data (Check if there is a Lead within the Call Hooks) ? I've no ideia on how to query relationships.

Comment: In the Calls logic hook the bean will have a parent_id and a parent_type. Check for parent_type == 'Leads'.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using professional version you need to create a workflow and customize the email template (everything using sugar interface in admin panel).

If you are using the community version you need to create `logic hooks` file and create you logic manually. I suggest you create one `$old_lead` in `before save hook` and compare this `$old_lead` with actual `$bean` and see if have one changes.